# SceneBuilder JavaFX using a Textbox, create a new line as per comma, from data received

Tags: java, javafx

I am building a tradebot, and I created my own UI. I gather data about my account via the API, and setText into a text field (as image shows). What I want to do, is be able to create a new line using the commas as a break, or be able to make some sort of excel table to separate the data and make it easy to use.
When I call for the data, it just dumps everything into a long, line of text.
Any suggestions on how to achieve this?
thanks,
Arthur
[image: UI]

```
@FXML
void onPositionClick(ActionEvent event) 
{
    
    Context ctx = new Context("https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY");
    
    try 
    {
        
        AccountSummary summary = ctx.account.summary(
        new AccountID("101-XXX-XXXXXX-XXX")).getAccount();
        
        String summaryString = String.valueOf(summary);
        
        displayResults.setText(summaryString);
            
    } //end try
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }//end catch
```

Comment: that's plain java language basics (nothing specific to fx nor scene builder) - time to work through a tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `System.lineSeparator()` because its system-dependent:

```
String text = "abc,de,fghi,jklmn,o";

String newText = text.replaceAll(",", System.lineSeparator());

System.out.println(newText);
```

**Output:**

```
abc
de
fghi
jklmn
o
```

Comment: Thank you! Here's what I ended up with:                                                                                            String summaryString = String.valueOf(summary);
String summarySeperated = summaryString.replaceAll("," ,  System.lineSeparator());
displayResults.setText(summarySeperated);  Again thanks for the help!!!

Comment: I'm glad it helped ;)